# Using re.compile and re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I would like to remove urls from my text:

```
#Django url validator https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py
regex = re.compile(
    r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://'  # http:// or https://
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'  # domain...
    r'localhost|'  # localhost...
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'  # ...or ipv4
    r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'  # ...or ipv6
    r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
    r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
text = "http://test.com word1 word2 https://test.de word3"
text = re.sub(regex, '', text)
print  text
```

the output is still :

```
http://test.com word1 word2 https://test.de word3
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is anchored to the beginning and end of the string with the `^` and `$` characters. So just remove them:

```
regex = re.compile(
    r'(?:http|ftp)s?://'  # http:// or https://
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'  # domain...
    r'localhost|'  # localhost...
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'  # ...or ipv4
    r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'  # ...or ipv6
    r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
    r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)', re.IGNORECASE)
```